# How do I use Java online on my web server?

Tags: java

I just started learning Java, and I have no idea how it works. The programming language I learned before this was PHP.

My question is, how do I use Java on my website? I created a .java file and it showed up like this (it showed the script): http://cpcheats.co/java/learning/index.java

I'm guessing I need to upload java onto my web server. If I do, can you please tell me where to download it, and where to upload it? If I don't need to download Java, can you please tell me how to use it on my website? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? JSP? Servlets? Applets?

Comment: Look into Play Framework

Comment: I don't know what any of those are. Sorry, I just starting learning Java today.

Comment: You need to do a lot more research about Java and what you want to use it for.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to run a java program on their website. Right? If you are wanting to build a website with it, look again. It's not that great at doing it (JSP and such...)

Comment: Here's a primer on Java web applications to get some keywords for further learning: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaWebTerminology/article.html

Comment: Another thing to note is that running a Java program is unlike running a PHP script.  Files with the .java extension do not execute, as they are simply java source files.  To run a java file, it needs to be compiled, which requires the Java Development Kit (JDK).

Comment: How do you compile a .java file?

Comment: You need to read a good Java book.  (eg, Core Java)

Comment: If I were you I 'd start with ruby instead of java, the rails framework is great.. http://rubyonrails.org/. If you really want to build a fast java web app, try play framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm guessing I need to upload java onto my web server.

Ok....
Go to a bookstore/library and buy/borrow a book on Java. Spend a weekend on it and *when you have a programming question*, please post it here and many of us here will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you need first is to understand the basic concept of java, and of a java web application (java on the server). You need to follow a course and this is not the place to write a java getting started, because this already exist.

I suggest that you read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html

After a couple of hours you should have a better understanding of what java is and what you can do with it.